# Rendering problems Android Studio Theme

Tags: android, android-layout

This pop up appears in my layout

> **Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?**
>   Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>
> Failed to find '?attr/textEditSuggestionItemLayout' in current theme.
>   (12 similar errors not shown)
>   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

This is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

What is my error?

Comment: ignore it just run the code?

Comment: Probably related bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225105

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes for dynamically inflated views like listviews and others like it , just run the code it should work just fine . It usually works fine for me. if it persists you can always goto : File>invalidate caches and restart.

Thats like the ctrl + alt + del for the android studio. Hope it helps. :D